# [Ruby]: Bad Uri Error

Tags: ruby, web, get

how can I fix the bad uri problem? I get these message.

The Code

```
puts "GET ?"
input = "https://www.xxxxxxxxxx.de/odata/"+gets+"/"


uri = URI.parse(input)
```

Comment: It's also a good idea to take input via the command-line, not via the terminal. For example, replace `gets` with `ARGV[0]`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will do that

Answer (score 3):

The result of `gets`ends with `\n`, a newline. Not wanted here, so chomp it:

```
 input = "https://www.xxxxxxxxxx.de/odata/" + gets.chomp + "/"
```